# Фильтр по БД используя multiple checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Есть форма на сайте с `multiple chekcbox(colors)`. Есть таблицы в БД объекты и цвета.

**object**

```
object_id|name
        1| one
        2| two
        3| three
```

**colors**

```
object_id|color_name
        1| red
        1| white
        2| red
        3| white
```

Выбрая в фильтре `red` и `white`, я хочу чтобы выводился только первый объект.

Правильно ли так проектировать БД и как осуществить этот запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос по фильтру с двумя параметрами:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM  colors WHERE color_name IN ('red', 'white')
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING  (COUNT(distinct object_id) = 2)
```

В `IN` указываете нужные цвета.

`COUNT(distinct object_id)` = количество аргументов в `IN`

В итоге получите идентификатор нужного объекта (либо их список). Можно сделать сразу в этом же запросе `Join` с первой таблицей, чтобы выводить еще и название объекта.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! То что нужно!

Comment: Хорошо, можно узнать зачем нужно считать количество не повторяющихся object_id HAVING  (COUNT(distinct object_id) = 2) ?

Comment: По сути можно просто указать count(*), но не у всех это срабатывает. ..

Comment: Если Вы не укажете условие having, то будут выведены также объекты, у которых только красный или только белый.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Подниму репутацию, поставлю плюс!

Comment: Может надо проверять   color_name а не object_id ?
having count(DISTINCT color_name) >= 2
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/648af/12

Comment: Можно вообще не указывать столбец и просто написать count(*).